# PHP setTimezone seems to only work on NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

I seriously can't figure out why it seems that a timezone conversion doesn't work if an actual time value is stored in the database.  If the value is NULL this code does seem to convert the time correctly.

```
$tz = "America/Chicago";        
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($tz);

$tmp_dt = new DateTime($row_ShowsRS['actual_datetime']);
$tmp_dt->setTimezone($timezone);
$actual_datetime = $tmp_dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The datetimes are all stored in the DB in UTC.  I'm simply trying to pull these times back out of the DB and display them in the user's local timezone.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($row_ShowsRS['actual_datetime']);`?

Comment: Please provide *data* with the code. What do you have, what do you get, what do you expect?